# Ubuntu doesn't boot after upgrading kernel

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I've had Ubuntu 11.10 with 3.0.0.14 kernel working but sound was off, so I was using 3.0.0.13 which started having some problems. So, I decided to upgrade kernel to 3.1. Upgrade went perfectly (no error messages) but after reboot there is a violet screen.

- I turn the computer on and I have GRUB properly working, I choose 3.1 version and I get the violet screen or there is logo with dots, they turn all red, logo dissapears and I get the violet screen agan.
- Pressing `ctrl+alt+f` doesn't work, the same with the power button.
- I tried choosing an older kernel version, I get black screen with some things turning on, everything is ok, and it stops (no log in screen) I can press power button and it works, and turns computer off.
- I made a live CD on a pen drive but it gives a "boot error".
- I went to recovery mode and tried `startx` (gives a black screen with a locked mouse)
- `initx` (white terminal window in the corner in which I can't write anything).
- I don't now what I wrote but it gave something about Xorg problems. I also got i915 symbol problem (which I think I've seen before with working system I have Intel i5 and I've read it always gives it when there is no other graphics card on). I found a lot of similar problems but most of them was either to update, or nVidia problems – I have Radeon HD 5650
- I tried

  ```
  apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic
  ```

  it went without problems, but showed me that I have 3.0.0.15 kernel version.

What to do to boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Your actual question may be much more obvious to you than to your readers. Could you explicitly add a one-sentence question to the end of the story?