# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome hangs/freezes on boot after upgrading to kernel 5.4.0-73 in Windows VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, freeze

Similar to:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed in VirtualBox hang at boot up after system update](https://superuser.com/questions/1331617/ubuntu-18-04-lts-installed-in-virtualbox-hang-at-boot-up-after-system-update)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after update](https://superuser.com/questions/1586096/ubuntu-18-04-freezes-after-update)
- [Ubuntu doesn't boot after upgrading kernel](https://superuser.com/questions/374723/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-upgrading-kernel)

But this happened just now, after an upgrade to kernel version `5.4.0-73-generic`.

---

The graphical session freezes on boot (just a blank screen after the disk checking message). The text console still works (I can switch to it with Ctrl-Alt-F2).

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -a
Linux bionic-vbox-vm 5.4.0-73-generic #82~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 15:10:02 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

VirtualBox 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt 5.6.2) win64 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Fixed it by changing `Settings->System->Acceleration->Paravirtualization Interface`</s>

from `Default` to `KVM`.

It turns out, it doesn't really "hang" but rather fails to start updating the screen initially.

Resizing the VM window got the picture back.